# How to update all the records of a table in an entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to update all the records of the table and change the one column value but it is not working for me

What I tried:

```
public static void UpdateSellerAutoApprovalSettings(bool isSellerAutoApproved)
        {
            using (var context = GetDbContext())
            {
                context.SiteGroups
                    .AddOrUpdate(x => x.IsSellerAutoApproved, 
                    new SiteGroup { IsSellerAutoApproved = isSellerAutoApproved });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Though EF is very useful (if used correctly) don't forget that you don't HAVE to do everything through EF / Linq-to-SQL. Updating all columns in a table takes just two lines of SQL

Comment: Which version of EntityFramework do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [EntityFrmaework.Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/download) library like below

```
context.SiteGroups
         .Update(x => new SiteGroup { IsSellerAutoApproved = isSellerAutoApproved });
```

This will generate a SQL statement and you will not load all records into a application memory.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ForEach` extension method:

```
context.SiteGroups.ForEach(e => e.IsSellerAutoApproved = isSellerAutoApproved);
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the below approach.

you can use where in between SiteGroups and ForEach if you need conditional Update

```
public static void UpdateSellerAutoApprovalSettings(bool isSellerAutoApproved)
{
    using (var context = GetDbContext())
    {
        context.SiteGroups
               .ForEach( x => x.IsSellerAutoApproved = isSellerAutoApproved )
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting option "ForEach" instead ForEachAsync shows and using that it gives some error